# django form textarea allow vertical resize only

Tags: django, resize, textarea

in my django project I made a form using

```
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

It works out ok and I get this. The text area is resizeable both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

I would like to make it un-resizeable horizontally, what should I do? I tried adding "attrs=" to the textarea but can't figure out what to call... Please help... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this with a css rule:

```
resize: vertical;
```

So, one way is to give it a class

```
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextArea(attrs={"class": "message"}))
```

Then define a css rule

```
.message{
    resize: vertical;
}
```